# How to get URN for a model in tandem api?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-tandem

I am begineer and new to tandem.
I am trying to read and write property of a model from the javascript test bed. When I am trying to read from it is asking for the URN value. I am don't know from were I will get this URN value. Please guide me.

I tried to find it in the documentation but I was not able find it. Please guide me from where can I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Tandem the facility can have multiple models. So you need to start with facility URN - you can find it in your browser bar (see image below).

[image: Address bar with facility URN]

Once you have facility URN you can use [GET twins/:urn](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/tandem/v1/reference/quick_reference/tandem-data-twins-twinID-GET/) to get facility details. The **links** array contains URNs of linked models - check out the **modelId** property:

```
"links": [
  {
    "disciplines": null,
    "label": "LTU2022 - Arch.rvt",
    "main": true,
    "modelId": "urn:adsk.dtm:CTmdTcAoSwaP79cLYjn8xQ",
    "on": true,
    "accessLevel": "Owner"
  },
  {
    "disciplines": null,
    "label": "LTU2022 - MEP.rvt",
    "main": false,
    "modelId": "urn:adsk.dtm:IVkKaloKQpG2IQcsl1yDwA",
    "on": true,
    "accessLevel": "Owner"
  }
]
```

You can use [this example](https://github.com/autodesk-tandem/tutorial-rest/blob/main/assets/read-asset-properties.js) to read asset properties and [this example](https://github.com/autodesk-tandem/tutorial-rest/blob/main/assets/write-asset-properties.js) to update them.

Comment: Thanks for update Jan. If you may say as where should I use that GET method for getting the urn of model. I am currently working in the autodesk test bed. I don't have any separate environment. So, Can you guide me as to how I can get the urn of model also.

Comment: Also Can you please guide me as where I should start with tandem api? Because I know flutter and I need use this tandem api for my project but I am unable to understand as to where to start it and how to use it? If you could please help me to understand where to start and go using the api.

Comment: Hi @Prv - are you using Viewer test bed or REST test bed, pls? Tandem API is REST based API so basically you need to call endpoint above to get facility details.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Understood I will try to work from here.